# Reading a text file that contains a number and a string

Tags: c++, file

I am new to C++ and I am currently exploring things. Now I am on reading a text file. This is the code:

```
while (myfile.good()) {
        myfile >> tempNum;
        getline(myfile, tempName);
        getline(myfile, tempCourse);
        myfile >> tempTuition;
        if (myfile.eof()) break;
        Student temp(tempNum, tempName, tempCourse, tempTuition);
        students.push_back(temp);
    }
```

Now my file currently contains this:

```
201699856
Justin Chu
BSITDA
36889
```

Problem is, with my current code, it reads like this.

- tempNum = 201699856
- tempName = ""
- tempCourse = "Justin Chu"
- tempTuition = "BSITDA"

At tempTuition, my program freezes because it contains an invalid data. Why is the getline() skipping the 2nd line? And how can I fix the program to read correctly?

Comment: You loop is almost equivalent to `while(!myfile.eof())`, so please read [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong)

Comment: Also see [How does reading file with while loops work in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14009737/608639) and [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5605125/608639)

Comment: Thanks for the links. So I saw that you can chain the input like while(stream>>variable>>variable). But how will it work for variables that has an int and a string? String when read, gives a single word with no whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

From [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline#Notes):

When used immediately after whitespace-delimited input, e.g. after `int n; std::cin >> n;`, getline consumes the endline character left on the input stream by operator>>, and returns immediately. A common solution is to ignore all leftover characters on the line of input with `cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');` before switching to line-oriented input.

Comment: Is this applicable to reading lines in text file? I mean the cin.ignore() part?